# Number of users in one resource Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I recently used keycloak as an authorisation server for my application that manipulate some kind of workspaces, so i created a resource in keycloak for each workspace and assigned users to it using keycloak console administration.
i wonder if there is a some kind of endpoint in keycloak API or another way  to get the number of users assigned to a resource.